# What is the name of the embroidery stitch which looks like tiny lines with gaps betweeen them?

Tags: embroidery, technique-identification

What is the name of this kind of embroidery stitch:

[image]

[Source: https://www.kollabora.com/projects/free-leaf-embroidery-pattern]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this encyclopedia of embroidery stitches](http://www.embroidery.rocksea.org/stitch/running-stitch/darning-stitch/), it looks like this is a "darning stitch", which is in the running stitch family.

> The darning stitch is about making rows of straight running stitches near each other. The technique of darning is used to mend  torn clothes, especially socks and looks like a woven patch.

Other sites corroborate this terminology.

The Wikipedia page for "[running stitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_stitch)" defines the darning stitch as:

> Darning stitches are closely spaced parallel rows of running stitches used to fill or reinforce worn areas of a textile, or as decoration.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that this style of embroidery is called ([sashiko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sashiko_stitching) from the Japanese technique.